# Scala returning a list with certain elements filtered out

Tags: scala, data-structures

I'm trying to take an existing list, run a function on each element, and if that function returns false, filter it out from the list.

I don't quite understand functional programming obviously because I tried the below:

```
for (elem <- myList) {      
  if(is_legal(elem) == false) {
    myList.filter(_ != elem)
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: if you have a list, say ("abcd", "xyz", "lol"), and a function that returns true or false and takes one of these strings as the argument.

I want to return the list without all the elements for which the function returns false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea in using `filter`; all you have to do is pass in the `is_legal` predicate:

```
val filteredList = myList.filter(is_legal)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I tried as follows:

`val newList = oldList.filter((is_legal(arg1, arg2)(_)))`

Returns `List((8,5), (6,5), (5,6), (5,8))`

Should return `List((6,5), (5,6))`

Comment: Sorry dude, problem was with my is_legal function. It passed the tests of the assignment grader, but it was still incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding for you above answer could be represented as

```
val filteredList = myList.filter(is_legal(_))
```

Or

```
val filteredList = myList.filter(x => is_legal(x))
```